# DataFrame Initialization with null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a dataframe with One row whose values are null.

```
val df = Seq(null,null).toDF("a","b")
```

Faced issues even if we used null.instanceof also with no success.

```
val df = Seq(null.asInstanceOf[Integer],null.asInstanceOf[Integer]).toDF("a","b")
```

This works but I don't like to specify the type of field mostly it should be string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a two-column DF, in that case each entry should be a tuple or a case-class. If that's the case, you can also explicitly state the type of the `Seq` so that you don't have use `asInstanceOf`:

```
val df = Seq[(Integer, Integer)]((null, null)).toDF("a","b")
```

Comment: Can we get nulltype which we get if we use withColumn("a",lit(null))  import org.apache.spark.sql.types.NullType. I mean right know schema is integer and integer. I am loking for null, null

df.withColumn("test", lit(null)).printSchema
root
 |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- test: null (nullable = true)

Comment: How is `NullType` useful? Anyway, I think the best way to achieve that is using an explicit schema, as suggested by @MansoorBabaShaik

Comment: NullType makes more sense than String or Integer types. I think that the reason behind the NullType when we use the lit

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way is to use `Option.empty[A]`:

```
val df = Seq((Option.empty[Int],Option.empty[Int])).toDF("a","b")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like missprint in "asInstanceOf", worked fine for me:

```
       List(null.asInstanceOf[Integer],null.asInstanceOf[Integer]).toDF("a").show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}

object SparkApp extends App {

  val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Spark_Test_App")
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()

  val schema: StructType = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("a", IntegerType, nullable = true),
      StructField("b", IntegerType, nullable = true)
    )
  )

  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val nullRDD: RDD[Row] = Seq((null, null)).toDF("a", "b").rdd

  val df: DataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(nullRDD, schema)

  df.printSchema()

  df.show()

  sparkSession.stop()
}
```